# Force usage of “var” to be parsed as keyword rather than class name

Tags: c#

Is it possible to force C# compiler to treat `var` as a **keyword** and not as a **class identifier** when a class of name `var` is declared?

```cs
public class var
{
}

public class A
{
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a=new A{};  // Cannot implicitly convert type 'A' to 'var'
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/O1wVoO

Comment: Why would you want to name your class "var" to begin with? What is a "var"?

Comment: `var` is NOT a reserverd keyword, it is a contextual keyword. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/#contextual-keywords

Comment: Kenneth K.: the problem emerged from auto-generated code. I was quite perplexed why "var o=new X();" throws compile time error.

Comment: This is indeed a true issue that the language permits, although afaik, only with classes having keyword names, I believe it does not happen for variables named `var`, so `var var = 5` is perfectly ok, nevertheless weird. Anyway, keywords are lowercased, those who follow naming conventions shouldn't ever have this problem. All bets off for generated code though but... do you really want to use generated code that is not even able to follow such simple guidelines?

Comment: Quick, someone summon the great one.

Comment: @Franta you can use `A a = new A { };`, but `var` keyword will be treated as instance of `var` type, not the keyword

Comment: @rph - sure, the code generator is not the problem, I can fix it easily. But the fact that you can redefine "var" and break existing code with it is little weird. I wonder why it's not a keyword. Then I could use verbatim when referencing that class.

Comment: This is great and works for other contextual keywords, too

Comment: @Franta Actually it was made _to not break existing code_. C# team avoid adding new reserved keywords to avoid breaking existing code, so when `var` was introduced, it was not made an reserved keyword, but contextual one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/reserved-and-contextual-keywords

Comment: @Magnetron but isn't it gonna break the code eventually?

Comment: @dorukerenaktas What is “the” code? It was made such that it couldn’t break *existing* code, because existing code that used `var` continued to compile, with identical semantics, in (then) new versions of C# even after `var`’s introduction as a contextual keyword.

Comment: @KonradRudolph oh i get it thanks.

Comment: Same problem for `dynamic`and `async`.

Comment: Just as @Magnetron said. Imagine if suddenly in a future C# version `index` or `value` become reserved words. Probably 99% of the code all over the world would stop compiling.

Comment: Rather than changing the compiler, have you thought about adding an inspection to the IDE? E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix

Comment: Just for the sake of making your code work, you can make your class A inherit your var class :)

Comment: @Magnetron thanks for the link, it occurred to me it could be because of backwards compatibility. But now it can be used to DOS IDE if the code base is big enough and always uses var. And also to prank your co-workers by randomly redefining contextual keywords :D

Comment: @PharazFadaei lol

Comment: Why do you want this edge case? So you name the class accordingly as A but 'var' as var instead of Var, capitalized as standard? This is why naming convention exists. This is a nice edge case as a chat over the coffee break, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you can no longer use `var` as a keyword within the context.

`var` is a contextual keyword (there are two types of [keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/): *normal* and *contextual*), where it behaves like a keyword within its respective contexts where it is used as a type name, but can still be used as an identifier (*not reserved*).

You declared it as class name therefore it loses its special meaning within the context.

Answer (score -1):

Can you declare var class name as @var and check. @forces keywords to behave like variables.

Comment: The question is asking for the other way around - how to make a variable behave like a keyword.

Comment: Verbatim (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) works when the name you want to use is equivalent to some reserved keyword. However, "var" is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: @Franta Having a variable begin with `@` is valid regardless of the variable name.  It doesn't need to be a reserved keyword for it to be valid.  So it will behave exactly the same as if you omitted it, but you *can* provide the redundant `@`.

Answer (score -3):

yes of course you can do that:

```
namespace vartest
{

    public class var {
        public var()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("It is me!");
        }
    }
}
namespace myform {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vartest.var theVar = new vartest.var();
            var a = "whatever";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can understand the trick is in the namespace ;-)
Thus in your case to protect the c# var, define your var class at its own namespace which you should not be "using".

Cheers

Comment: You have not shown how to use the `var` contextual keyword when an identifier named "var" is in scope.  Your code doesn't use the contextual keyword, as requested.  You just wrote code using the class called `var`, which wasn't the problem.